# Misunderstanding or possible violation of Generic Subtyping Rules in Java

Tags: java, generics, exception, wildcard

Code snippet is from OSP Java certification guide

```
List<? super IOException> exceptions = new ArrayList<Exception>();
        exceptions.add(new Exception());  // DOES NOT  COMPILE
        exceptions.add(new IOException());
        exceptions.add(new FileNotFoundException());
```

I should remind the rules we follow.

**Lower-bound** is when you specify (`? super Field`) means argument can be any Field or superclass of Field.

By this rule `? super IOException` means we can add any object whose declared class is `IOException` or superclass of it.

Then why we cannot add `Exception` object in our List but we can add `FileNotFoundException` object, which is subtype `IOException` class.

Maybe I misinterpreted declared classes and instances of class or generic bounds, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are mixing up two different concepts:

When we say `? super IOException` means you can make below assignments:

```
List<? super IOException> foo = new ArrayList<IOException>();  // IOException is a "superclass" of IOException
List<? super IOException> foo = new ArrayList<Exception>();   // Exception is a superclass of IOException
List<? super IOException> foo = new ArrayList<Object>();   // Object is a superclass of IOException
List<? super IOException> foo = new ArrayList<FileNotFoundException>();   // Compilation error as FileNotFoundException is a not superclass of IOException
```

And super class reference(`IOException`) can old the object of sub-class (`FileNotFoundException`)

```
List<? super IOException> exceptions = new ArrayList<Exception>();
exceptions.add(new Exception());  // DOES NOT  COMPILE as It's Super class to IOException
exceptions.add(new IOException()); // IOException is a "superclass" of IOException
exceptions.add(new FileNotFoundException()); // IOException is a "superclass" of FileNotFoundException
```

Comment: I appreciate your first block of code, but about second...

List<? super IOException> exceptions = new ArrayList<Exception>();
By which generic parameter we should rely on, when we decide add specific object?
Because if we rely on <? super IOException> it means we can add Exception object as superclass  IOException
Or we if we rely on  generic parameter from instance <Exception> it means we can also add Exception object
I am sorry  for wasting your time, Gaurav Jeswani, but I will be glad if you make clear explanation about that

Comment: List<? super IOException> defines the reference and new ArrayList<IOException>(); defines the object. And compile time it checks for reference and runtime it loads the objects. So for compile time we need to obey the contracts of reference. Here reference says about IOException. So it should follow that.

Comment: Welcome, Please consider accepting the answer if it was helpful. So that others can also refer it.